# Set gradient for Android ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, xml-drawable

I use an ActionBarSherlock library in my app. I also needed to customize the ActionBar, so I added a custom theme with a `background` parameter set, like this:

```
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">

<item name="background">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>

<item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>

</style>
```

`action_bar_bg` drawable is simply a bitmap of tiled squares:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true"
    android:src="@drawable/bg_img_actionbar"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

What I want to do next is to set a linear gradient for a whole ActionBar, so it will cover this background. And I have no idea if it's possible and how to do that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a type of resource for this, Shape Drawable:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Comment: Yes, but from what I can see it allows me to set the image's color, not tiled background.

Comment: I don't understand you. Tile or gradient? Do you want both simultaneously?

Comment: Yes. Currently I have an ActionBar with a tiled background and I want to add a linear gradient on top of it as well.

Comment: Combinando ShapeDrawable y LayerList creo que podría conseguirlo.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList

Comment: You're a genious! I completely forgot about the `<layer-list>`! Thank you ;)

Comment: Just to translate JMPergars comment: Combine shape drawable with LayerList and that should work: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList